# Issue with Profile in ASP.NET Web Forms application

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, profile

I am trying to use Profile in an ASP.NET web Forms application and I have run into a maddening problem I can't resolve.
I know that if I have profiles set up (and include the `System.Web.Profile` namespace) then I should be able to access profile information on the current user by using this code:

```
Profile.LastName=... \\ assumes I have a defined profile property for last name, of course
```

But IntelliSense doesn't show 'Profile' as an option, and if I try to use it anyway, I get the error `Profile doesn't exist in the current context`.  So, instead, I am trying to do it this way:

In my `.aspx` code-behind file, I have the following code:

```
            ProfileCommon profile = HttpContext.Current.Profile as ProfileCommon;
            profile.LastName = last;
            profile.FirstName = first;
            profile.BestContactEmail = email;
            profile.Save ( );
```

The first line runs properly, and the 'profile' variable shows the defined properties, but trying to access those properties throws the error that `profile is null`.

I don't understand what I'm missing here.  Why is this not working?

Comment: When you use the `as T` syntax, if that object can't be converted to T, then it will be null. So this means HttpContext.Current.Profile is either null or can't be converted to ProfileCommon. Why don't you just do `var profile = HttpContext.Current.Profile`?

Comment: When I do that, it doesn't expose/have any of the defined profile properties that I declared in the web.config file.  It throws an error saying "ProfileBase does not contain definitiion for..." and the property name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after fiddling around with this for a full day, I found a way to make it work, because for some reason, retrieving the member's profile using `var profile = HttpContext.Current.Profile;` doesn't work.

In light of this, I found that this works, at least to the extent of creating a profile and storing its data in the database:

```
var profile = ProfileBase.Create(uname.Value);
profile.SetPropertyValue ( "LastName", last_name.Value );
profile.SetPropertyValue ( "FirstName", first_name.Value );
profile.Save ( );
```

Weird, but it works.